# how to distribute a .ipa file without appstore and apple developer account?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have created a .ipa file with flutter using diawi. I want to know is there any way that I can distribute my app among my users without adding their UDIDs to my app and without appstore and apple developer account? I am looking for some kind of website that give OTA from .ipa

Comment: Without app store: It is possible(Go with enterprise account) but without apple developer account seems not possible. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programming question and most probably will be closed but for your sake I'll answer.

You can distribute your app on your own using an Enterprise Apple Account. It costs 3x more than regular account. And according to the Terms of Conditions the users must be from your business not from anywhere else (If you have to distribute to public you must use App Store).

You can also try TestFlight and add your users email to your testing group and then they will be able to download the app through TF without you adding their UUIDs. This way you can have 10k testers at most.